# Geoserver Custom Map (XYZ) in Traccar

Tags: geoserver, xyz-tiles

I have the following issue with my Geoserver XYZ map that I am pulling into Traccar. My tiles are not pulling through correctly as seen in the image below.
[image]

And here is my XYZ map URL: [http://196.41.13.52:8888/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/ramm-live-data%3ACapetown@EPSG%3A4326@png/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?flipY=true](http://196.41.13.52:8888/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/ramm-live-data%3ACapetown@EPSG%3A4326@png/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png?flipY=true)

Comment: what happens if you don't flip the Y?

Comment: Nothing, it looks the same.

Comment: I have come up with a solution for anyone that will struggle with this in the future. 1.) You need the latest version of Geoserver to generate Slippy tiles (XYZ map). 2.) You need to use the Gridset EPSG 3857 as this is the CRS that Traccar uses. 3.) And then you need to following structure for your URL to work http://IP:Port/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/Workspace%3ALayer@Gridset@png/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?flipY=true